# An integration limit

Tags: real-analysis

Given $z\geq 0$, denote
$$A_m(z) = \{x\in \mathbf R^{m-1}\, :\, \min_{1\leq i\leq m-1} x_i > z\},$$
and
$$F_m(z) = \int_{A_m(z)} (1+|x|^2)^{1-m} dx.$$
Does the following limit
$$\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sqrt{m}(m-2)\int_0^1 (1-z)^{m-3}\frac{F_m(z)}{F_m(0)} dz$$
exist?

It is interesting if we know the value of this limit. If anyone know the references for this problem, please let me know.

Thanks in advances

Comment: Welcome to the site. For context could you please explain why is it interesting to know the limit?

Comment: You have an $n-3$ in an exponent in the last integral.  What is $n$?

Comment: @S.Carnahan: Almost surely that is an $m$. I have edited the post accordingly.